# Default of malloc'd bool value within struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, boolean

What is the value of this bool within a struct when we try to access it as n->myBool? I'm interested to know what the "default" value of the bool is after allocating memory for it but not assigning it a true of false value.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
typedef struct node
{
 bool myBool;
} Node;

void main()
{
 Node* n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
 return;
}
```

edit: corrected a typo in code (should be sizeof(Node) not sizeof(node)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no default value. Space allocated by `malloc` is uninitialized, and trying to read from `n->myBool` before writing a value to it will cause undefined behaviour.